# MODx : Container resource vs. resource's parent

Tags: modx, modx-revolution, modx-resources

What are the use of container resource and the use of resource's parent?
Are they relevant to each other?

Answer (score 0):

We need more information, but I will try my best.

Im going to assume that Container Resources and Parent Resources are the same things.

Parent resources are resources (aka pages) that have child resources under them. You can use a parent resource to organise your resources on the site, eg: using the getResource plugin to display all child resources on a page.

You can also use Wayfinder to display child resources as sub menus.

Example of getResources call:

```
[[!getResources? &parents=`5` &limit=`10` &tpl=`blogPost`]]
```

This is saying:

> "Get the child resources of the parent resource with ID 5. Limit the
>   number of child resources returned to 10. Render them with the
>   template blogPost"